# Showing that every collection of disjoint open subsets is countable

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a second countable topological space. Show that every collection of disjoint open subsets of X is countable.

**Proof:** Let $X$ be a second countable space. Choose ${\{B_{i}\}{_i\in \mathbb{N}} }$ to be our countable basis for the topology on $X$. Let $C$ be any collection of disjoint open subsets of $X$. Our goal is to show that $C$ is countable. More formally, let $C=\{U_{i} \in \{B_{i}\}\subseteq X  | \: i \in \mathbb{N}, \: U_{i} \bigcap U_{j} = \emptyset \}$. Now $C$ is countable since for every $U_{i} \in \{B_{i}\} $ there is a correspondence between $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus it follows that $C$ is countable.

Is the construction of the set $C$ precise or is their a better way.

Comment: Your statement "More formally..." actually asserts that every member of C is a member of the base.

Comment: The weight $w(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $W$ such that $X$ has a base of cardinal $W$ or less. The density $d(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $D$ such that $X$ has a dense set of cardinal $D$ or less. The cellularity $c(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $C$ such that every discrete open family (a family of pair-wise disjoint open sets) has cardinal at most $C.$... For any $X$ we have $ w(X)\geq d(X)\geq c(X).$... There is much about these, and other topological cardinal functions, in General Topology by R. Engelking.

Comment: I've read some basic set theory, but I find your notation $$C=\{U_{i} \in \{B_{i}\}\subseteq X  | \: i \in \mathbb{N}, \: U_{i} \bigcap U_{j} = \emptyset \}
$$ incomprehensible. This is not my only problem, but to start with, doesn't $U_i\in\{B_i\}$ just mean $U_i=B_i$?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\{B_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable base for $X$.

Then let $\mathcal{U}$ be any family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open sets.

For every $U \in \mathcal{U}$ find $x \in U$ and as we have a base, there is some $n(U) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in B_{n(U)} \subseteq U$.

This defines a function: $f: \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(U) = n(U)$. If $U \neq V$ then $n(U) \neq n(V)$ otherwise $m = n(U) = n(V)$ and then $\neq = B_m \subseteq U_{n(U)} \cap U_{n(V)}$, a contradiction with the disjointness of $\mathcal{U}$. So $f$ is 1-1 and so $\mathcal{U}$ is at most countable.

Comment: How is this function $f$  well-defined? Doesn't the number you denote by $n(U)$ also depend on which point you choose in $U$? Given $U\in\mathcal{U}$, you could find two points in $U$ which may give two different natural numbers.

Comment: @kmiyazaki it doesn’t matter that it depends on $X$. If we have such  a function at all, we’re done. If it matters to you, let $n(U)=\min\{n: B_n \subseteq U\}$ which is uniquely defined. I wasn’t claiming uniqueness but this does make it unique.

Answer (score 2):

In your construction of $C$, you're assuming it's countable (its elements are indexed by a countable set).  What you should do is start with an arbitary collection $C=\{U_\alpha\}$ of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $X$, then show that $C$ is countable.

Hint: Each $U_\alpha$ contains some $B_\alpha$, and since $U_\alpha\displaystyle\cap U_\beta=\varnothing$ if $\alpha\neq\beta$, we know that $B_\alpha\displaystyle\cap B_\beta=\varnothing$ if $\alpha\neq\beta$.

Comment: Thanks. I figured something was out of place.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.